# PHP Regular expression to find scripts in head

Tags: php, html, regex

I need regular expression to be used in PHP that can extract all script tags links (**src** attributes).

i already have this regex which i created to extract script src values but i'm unable to make it work to find only in the **head** section

`/<script [^>]*src=["|\']([^"|\']+(\.js))/i`

hoping someone will check this and test before sending a new regex that can work.

Comment: Don't parse html with regex: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/372239

Comment: Thank you for your comment, But I specifically need regex for this particular scenario and i'm aware of the limitations. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
/html/head/script/@src
```

Easy peasy. Obviously *not* a regex, it's xpath. [Not good things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3942918) tend to happen when you try to parse HTML with regular expressions. Fortunately a more capable HTML parser comes with PHP's [DOM extension](http://php.net/dom) - exposed by the [`loadHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and [`loadHTMLFile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) methods.

This lets you work with all the wonderful DOM methods as well as [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) for querying the document.

---

#### Example:

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<html>
<head>
    <script src="foo.js"></script>
    <script src="bar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="baz.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('/html/head/script/@src') as $src) {
    echo $src->value, "\n";
}
```

---

#### Output:

```
foo.js
bar.js
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I specifically want regex since i'm using it already in my application. So, dom parsers etc. wont work.